# How to translate CakePHP's core domain strings with POEdit?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, poedit

It's not the first time I set up POEdit to work with CakePHP, but it's the first time I need to translate core strings on a site. Specifically, I need to translate the strings on `TimeHelper`'s `timeAgoInWords()` function. The problem is that all strings in there are encapsulated in `__d()` and `__dn()` functions (instead of regular `__()`, `__n()`, etc), which use the translation domain name as the first parameter, instead of the translatable string. So if I tell POEdit to include `__d` and `__dn` as keywords in the catalog, it thinks "cake" and "cake_dev" are translatable strings.

What's the best way to translate CakePHP's core strings that on the "cake" domain?

You can see the code of `timeAgoInWords` [here](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/time-helper#line-501).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer hidden here on SO. A combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407840/poedit-keywords-plurals) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393139/how-to-make-poedit-correctly-parse-custom-ngettext-implementation) question:

- First, I added the `__d` keyword in the form of `__d:2` so it took the second parameter instead of the first.
- I also added a `__dn:2,3` keyword.
- Then I configured the plural forms (`nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;`) on POEdit in order to make the previous keyword work.

All worked like a charm.

I hope this helps somebody else.